# Pinterest redirect uri not working

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I'm trying to use Pinterest apis for fetching some information. In order to get access to that, I need access token which can be returned using Pinterest Javascript SDK, PDK. Refer to [this](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/js/) I'm able to integrate in my web app but when trying to fetch the token, it gives me following response:

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 7, "host": "coreapp-ngapi-prod-cc8abc1f", "generated_at": "Sat, 03 Oct 2015 08:05:09 +0000", "message": "You are not permitted to access that resource.", "data": "The provided redirect_uri does not match any of the registered redirect URIs."}
```

Also, on looking at the Pinterest app which I have created, it seems that redirect uris field is empty even though I gave that redirect uri initially during intitial registration. If I try to update that field, there is no option of Save my changes. Can anyone please tell me any work around ? Also, I have tried using basic site url in redirect params and https but still no help.

Thanks

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Any help??

Answer (score 3):

So it's not obvious in their interface how to properly set up URIs -- what you need to do is just press ENTER and then it adds to a list of URIs below that textbox.  And each one must be https:// -- they don't allow redirects to unencrypted pages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks, @KrzysztofTrzos
Quite a catch-22 for the newcomer with not having rep / still wanting to help.